The orthogonal projection to $W_1\cap W_2$ is given by $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$. What is the domain of this projection? ("Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.)
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.
The author wrote "The above proof also shows that the orthogonal projection to $W_1\cap W_2$ is given by $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$".
I don't understand this sentence.
The author wrote "$A_1A_2=A_2A_1$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W_1\cap W_2$.".
But the author didn't write about the domain vector space of this orthogonal projection at all.
Is the domain vector space of this orthogonal projection $W_1$ or $W_2$?
And the domain vector space of this orthogonal projection is not the entire vector space $V$?


The domain and codomain of all the projections should be $V$.  One must infer that both $W_1,W_2$ are subspaces of $V$ (based on the lack of "$V$" in the question text, I would tend to assume it was a previously stated convention for the text)

@BrianMoehring thank you very much for your comment.


Let $W:=\{x\in V:A_1A_2x=x\}$.
Let $W':=\{x\in V:A_1A_2x=0\}$.
Then, $W=A_1A_2V$ and $W'=(I_n-A_1A_2)V$.

Proof:
Let $x\in W$.
Then, $x=A_1A_2x\in A_1A_2V$.
Let $x\in A_1A_2V$.
Then, $x=A_1A_2v$ for some $v\in V$.
$A_1A_2x=A_1A_2(A_1A_2v)=(A_1A_2)^2v=A_1A_2v=x$.
So, $x\in W$.
Let $x\in W'$.
Then, $A_1A_2x=0$.
$x=I_nx=I_nx-0=I_nx-A_1A_2x=(I_n-A_1A_2)x\in (I_n-A_1A_2)V$.
Let $x\in (I_n-A_1A_2)V$.
Then, $x=(I_n-A_1A_2)v$ for some $v\in V$.
$A_1A_2x=A_1A_2(I_n-A_1A_2)v=A_1A_2v-(A_1A_2)^2v=A_1A_2v-A_1A_2v=0$.
So, $x\in W'$.

$V=W\oplus W'$.

Proof:
Let $x\in V$.
$x=A_1A_2x+(I_n-A_1A_2)x\in W+W'$.
So, $V=W+W'$.
Let $x\in W\cap W'$.
Then, $x=A_1A_2x=0$.
So, $V=W\oplus W'$.

$(A_1A_2)^T=A_2^TA_1^T=A_2A_1=A_1A_2$.
So, for $x\in W$ and for $y\in W'$, $(x,y)=(A_1A_2x,y)=(x,A_1A_2y)=(x,0)=0$.
So, $W\perp W'$.

$W=W_1\cap W_2$.

Proof:
Let $x\in W$.
$A_1A_2x=x$.
$x=A_1(A_2x)\in W_1$ and $x=A_2(A_1x)\in W_2$.
So, $x\in W_1\cap W_2$.
Let $x\in W_1\cap W_2$.
$A_2x=x$ since $x\in W_2$ and $A_1x=x$ since $x\in W_1$.
So, $A_1A_2x=A_1x=x$.
So, $x\in W$.

So, $V=(W_1\cap W_2)\oplus (W_1\cap W_2)^\perp$.
Let $x=x'+x''$ for $x'\in W_1\cap W_2$ and for $x''\in (W_1\cap W_2)^\perp$.
Then, the linear map $V\ni x\mapsto x'\in W_1\cap W_2$ is the orthogonal projection onto $W_1\cap W_2$.
And $x'=A_1A_2x$.
